# Google search is not displaying meta description of a blog

Tags: html, meta-tags

I have added meta tag description in my page, but it is not displaying when I search my page in google.

It is displaying something else from my blog page. Please let me know if any one is aware of this.

Thanks in advance!!

Anand

Comment: You can't expect the Meta description to be displayed. It's up to Google what they show

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The meta description is only a hint - it's not guaranteed to be used. If you search for your site like this: `site:watchcricket-online.blogspot.com` instead, then you'll see the meta description, verifying you've entered it correctly.

The snippet that is shown on the search engine result page depends on the keywords the person searches for, so you can't really target any specific text there.

You should also be aware that Google doesn't actually use the description as part of it's ranking algorithm - words that are in the description don't count as part of the page. (i.e. if your description was `wueoqwiueoiuoiauiouwqoeuq`, your page wouldn't rank for that term if the only place it was was in the description.)

Answer (score 2):

Google does not always show the meta description. If it finds something better on your site to use, it uses that snippet instead.

Look at [this article](http://www.seomoz.org/blog/why-wont-google-use-my-meta-description) to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

Google may or may not use meta tag descriptions. Mostly it doesn’t, because experience shows that they are widely used by site authors for excessive and often misleading advertising instead of informative content. But in special cases, especially when there are no useful matches for the search words in content, it may use meta tag descriptions, as you can see by googling with

url:watchcricket-online.blogspot.com